# What does the ending "-ón" signify?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática

**English:**

Consider the following:

> rata -> *ratón*
>
> puerta -> *portón*
>
> gata -> *gatón*

Does the *-ón* ending change anything? Which word should I use and why?

**Español:**

Considere lo siguente:

> rata -> *ratón*
>
> puerta -> *portón*
>
> gata -> *gatón*

¿Cambia el final *-ón* algo? ¿Cuál palabra debo usar y por qué?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *-ón<sub>(a)</sub>* ending (along with *-azo<sub>/a</sub>* and *-ote*) is what's called an **augmentative**.  Essentially, it's a bigger or more intense version of the base word (and the opposite of a diminuitive like *-ito<sub>/a</sub>* and similar).  Using *gato* you get:

- *small cat*: gatito, gatillo, gatín, etc
- *cat*: gato
- *big cat*: gatón, gatazo, gatote

You can do the same with other words like *libro* (*librón, librote* — big books), perro (*perrazo*, *perrote* — big dogs) or even *señor* (*señorón, señorote* — very manly man).

Pretty much any noun can *technically* have it added, but it definitely sounds weirder on some words than diminuitive endings (for example: *piscinita*, *piscina*, *piscinón*) and certain augmentatives may sound better on certain words.  When doing it, *in theory* you should pay attention to stem-changing vowels like in *puerta/portón*, but in practice these days that is not very well followed (hence you'll see both *puertazo* and *portazo*).

Like with the diminuitives, some versions have become lexicalized — that is, they have become words in their own right, often with their own specific, unpredictable, meaning (like *manzana*/*manzanilla*).  *Rata/ratón* is one of these, as obviously as *ratón* is smaller than a *rata*.  A *portón*, when it's not merely a large door, has other particular uses such as being the main door to the house or the gate to let bulls out.  In these cases, you need to carefully distinguish the two versions and use the correct one as they won't necessarily be interchangeable.

Comment: Also note that "portazo" means to slam a door against its frame. Happens a lot with "-azo" and things that can be used to smash things, like "mazo" o "martillo" (mazazo, martillazo). Even innocent thing like books: "le da un librazo en la cabeza por no prestar atención" (he/she hit him/her on the head with a book for not paying attention).